# Small script to update an external HDD every night at 23 in the background

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x

This is a small script to update an external HDD, every night at 23:00, in the background.

Can you tell me how I can improve it?

What section in this code can be written as a class? Maybe the `log` function?

This line -> `from distutils import dir_util`. How can I write this to follow the same format as my other `import`s?

```
###############################################################################
##  Description: This script is meant to update the HDD given the location from 
##               the HDD needs to be synced and where it should copy the files. 
##               The script will check how much space is on the external HDD 
##               will create a folder with today's date and copy the files in 
##               that folder 
## 
## Example Call: python3 syncHDD.py --SYNCHDD_DAYS_KEEP [integer] 
##                                  --SYNCHDD_FROM [path] 
##                                  --SYNCHDD_TO [path] 
##                                  --SYNCHDD_LOG [path]
##
## python3 syncHDD.py --SYNCHDD_DAYS_KEEP 5 --SYNCHDD_FROM <fromdir> --SYNCHDD_TO <toDir> --SYNCHDD_LOG <logFolder>
##
###############################################################################

###############################################################################
##     IMPORT UTILITIES  
###############################################################################
import importlib, sys

for moduleName in ['os', 're', 'math', 'datetime', 'distutils', 'sys', 'getopt', 'crontab', 'getpass']: 
    print('Importing ' + moduleName + " ... ", end="")
    try: 
        globals()[moduleName] = importlib.import_module(moduleName)
    except ModuleNotFoundError: 
       print('FAILED')
       sys.exit[1]
    print('SUCCESS')

from distutils import dir_util

###############################################################################
##     DEFINING FUNCTIONS
############################################################################### 
def hdfooter(vr):
    if(vr == 'header'):
        print('')
        print('========== STARTING FUNCTION ==========')
        print('')
    else:
        print('')
        print('========== **ENDING FUNCTION ==========')
        print('')

def getTimestamp():
    return datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y.%m.%dD%H.%M.%S.%f")

def getDate():
    return datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y.%m.%d")

def sep():
    if sys.platform.startswith('linux'):
        return '/'
    if sys.platform.startswith('win'):
        return '\\'

def createLogMessage(lvl,message):
    if (lvl == 0): 
        prefix = "[*INFO]|"
    elif (lvl == 1):
        prefix = "[ERROR]|"
    else:
        prefix = "[DEBUG]|"
    return prefix + getTimestamp() + "| " + message 

def openCloseLogFile(LFN, dV, action,file=None):
    #function to open the logfile and print the header and footer 
    #create log file in specified location 
    logFilePath = dV['SYNCHDD_LOG']
    logFilePath = logFilePath + "/" + LFN 
    if action == "open":
        if os.path.exists(logFilePath):
            #if file exists open to append new log messages
            file = open(logFilePath,"a+")
            file.write('========== STARTING FUNCTION ==========\n')
            return file
        else:
            #if files does not exist, create it.
            file = open(logFilePath,"w")
            file.write('========== STARTING FUNCTION ==========\n')            
            return file
    else:
        file.write('========== **ENDING FUNCTION ==========\n\n')
        file.close()

def log(lvl,message,file):
    #create log message
    message = createLogMessage(lvl,message)
    #print to file
    print(message)
    file.write(message)
    file.write('\n')

def convertBytesToMb(bytesValue):
    return bytesValue/1000000

def return_date_like_folders(fld):
    res = []
    for fname in fld: 
        if (re.match(r"\d+\.\d+\.\d+", fname)):
            res.append(fname)
    return res

def removeDays(path,dV,file):
    # check if SYNCHDD_DAYS_KEEP is defined and only keep the data copied for 
    # thos days 
    startTime = datetime.datetime.now()
    log(0,"removeDays: Removing data older than " + dV['SYNCHDD_DAYS_KEEP'] + " days ...",file)
    dt = return_date_like_folders(os.listdir(path))
    thresholdDate = (datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days = int(dV['SYNCHDD_DAYS_KEEP']))).strftime('%Y.%m.%d')
    for i in dt: 
        if (datetime.datetime.strptime(i,'%Y.%m.%d') < datetime.datetime.strptime(thresholdDate,"%Y.%m.%d")):
            try:
                log(0, "removeDays: Attempting to remove: " + path + i + "/", file)
                dir_util.remove_tree(path + i + "/")
            except OSError as e: 
                log(1,"removeDays: Failed to delete directory [" + (path + i + "/") + "] with error: " + e,file)

def getNecessarySpace(path,file):
    log(0,"getNecessarySpace: Getting necessary space ...",file)
    total_size = 0
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
        for f in filenames:
            fp = os.path.join(dirpath, f)
            total_size += os.path.getsize(fp)
    return math.ceil(convertBytesToMb(total_size))

def getAvailableSpace(path,file):
    log(2,"getAvailableSpace: Getting available space ...",file)
    return math.ceil(convertBytesToMb(os.statvfs(path).f_frsize * os.statvfs(path).f_bavail))

def createTodayFolder(path,file):
    folderName = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y.%m.%d")
    #list folder in directory and check if fodler for today already exists 
    if not folderName in os.listdir(path) :
        log(0,"createTodayFolder: Creating folder: " + folderName + " in " + path,file)
        try:
            os.mkdir(path + folderName)
        except OSError:
            log(2,"createTodayFolder: Failed to create folder " + folderName + " in " + path,file)
        else:
            log(0,"createTodayFolder: Successfully created folder " + folderName + " in " + path,file)
    else:
        log(1,"createTodayFolder: Folder already exists ...",file)
        sys.exit(2)
    return folderName

def copyFilesAccross(source, destination, file):
    #check if there is enough space
    startTime = datetime.datetime.now()
    log(0,"copyFilesAccross: Copying files ...",file)
    try:
        dir_util.copy_tree(source,destination)
        log(0,"Operation has completed successfully in: " + str(datetime.datetime.now() - startTime), file)
    except OSError as e:
        log(1,"copyFileAccross: Failed to copy from " + source + " to " + destination + " with error: " + e,file)

def checkEnvVar(eV,file):
    for v in eV: 
        if os.getenv(v) is None:
            log(1,'checkEnvVar: Environment variable: ' + v + ' has not been set. Function will terminate ...',file)
            sys.exit()

def getProgParams(arg, parName):
    #function to check if env var are defined if not take from command line
    #env variables have priority
    if os.getenv(parName) is None:
        print('getProgParams: Environment Variable Does Not Exist -> For variable '+ parName +' setting to ' + arg)
        return arg
    else: 
        print('getProgParams: Environment Variable Exists -> For variable '+ parName +' setting to ' + os.getenv(parName))
        return os.getenv(parName)

def getCmdLineArguments():
    #function to create a dictionary of arguments passed from the cmdline 
    dictVal = {}                                                               #Creating an empty dictionary
    argv = sys.argv[1:]
    dictVal['execLine'] = ' '.join([sys.executable] + [os.getcwd() + sep() + sys.argv[0]] + argv)
    try:
      opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv, "hd:f:t:l:" ,["SYNCHDD_DAYS_KEEP=", "SYNCHDD_FROM=", "SYNCHDD_TO=", "SYNCHDD_LOG="])
    except getopt.GetoptError:
      print('getCmdLineArguments: Failed to get command line arguments ...')
      sys.exit(2)
    for opt, arg in opts:
        if opt == '-h':
            print("\nHelp Message:\nsyncHDD.py --SYNCHDD_DAYS_KEEP [integer] --SYNCHDD_FROM [path] --SYNCHDD_TO [path] --SYNCHDD_LOG [path]\n")
            sys.exit()
        elif opt in ("-d", "--SYNCHDD_DAYS_KEEP"):
            dictVal['SYNCHDD_DAYS_KEEP'] = getProgParams(arg, 'SYNCHDD_DAYS_KEEP')
        elif opt in ("-f", "--SYNCHDD_FROM"):
            dictVal['SYNCHDD_FROM'] = getProgParams(arg, 'SYNCHDD_FROM')
        elif opt in ("-t", "--SYNCHDD_TO"):
            dictVal['SYNCHDD_TO'] = getProgParams(arg, 'SYNCHDD_TO')
        elif opt in ("-l", "--SYNCHDD_LOG"):
            dictVal['SYNCHDD_LOG'] = getProgParams(arg, 'SYNCHDD_LOG')
    return dictVal

def addToCron(eL, dV, file):
    #there are some errors in here that I need to sort out
    #seems to add the jobs quite a few times 
    #also seems to change the scheduling for other jobs 
    #function to add this job to the cron job if on linux
    log(0,'addToCron: Attempting to add a new job to cron',file)
    myCron = crontab.CronTab(user = getpass.getuser()) 
    scriptName = dV['execLine'].split(' ')[1].split('/')[-1]
    jobExists = False
    for job in myCron:
        if job.comment == scriptName:
            jobExists = not jobExists
    if not jobExists:
        log(0,'addToCron: Adding ' + dV['execLine'] + ' to crontab ...',file)
        job = myCron.new(command = dV['execLine'], comment='syncHDD.py')
        job.hour.on(23)
        #job.minute.every(5)
        try: 
            myCron.write()
            log(0,'Job has been successfully added to crontab ',file)
        except OSError as errorMessage: 
            log(1,'addToCron: Failed to write to crontab with OSError -> ' + str(errorMessage), file)
    else:
        log(1,'addToCron: Job ['+ scriptName +'] already exists',file)

def main():
    dictVal = getCmdLineArguments()
    print("RUNNING FUNCTION ...")
    hdfooter('header')
    logFileName = "logOutput_" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%dD%H%M%S%f") + ".log"
    file = openCloseLogFile(logFileName, dictVal, "open")
    log(0,"Log messages will be printed in: "+ logFileName,file)
    for elem in ['SYNCHDD_DAYS_KEEP','SYNCHDD_FROM','SYNCHDD_TO','SYNCHDD_LOG']:
        if not elem in list(dictVal.keys()):
            if os.getenv(elem) is None:
                log(1,'main: Variable '+ elem + ' is missing. Exiting ...',file)
                sys.exit(2)
            else: 
                log(0,'main: Variable '+ elem + ' will be set to ' + os.getenv(elem),file)
                dictVal[elem] = os.getenv(elem)
    ##checkEnvVar(["SYNCHDD_FROM","SYNCHDD_TO","SYNCHDD_LOG"],file)
    src = dictVal['SYNCHDD_FROM']
    destination = dictVal['SYNCHDD_TO']
    addToCron(dictVal['execLine'], dictVal, file)
    removeDays(destination,dictVal,file)
    log(0,"main: Moving from " + src + " to " + destination,file)
    #create folder with today's date 
    destination = destination + createTodayFolder(destination,file)
    necessarySpace = getNecessarySpace(src,file)
    availableSpace = getAvailableSpace(destination,file)
    if( necessarySpace > availableSpace):
        log(1,"main: Needed space is greater than available space. Necessary: " 
            + str(necessarySpace) 
            + " Available: " 
            + str(availableSpace),file)
    else:
            log(0,"main: Available space: " + str(availableSpace) + " Necessary space: " + str(necessarySpace), file)
            log(0,"main: There is enough space. Files can be copied",file)
            copyFilesAccross(src,destination,file)

    openCloseLogFile(logFileName, dictVal, "close", file)
    hdfooter('footer')

###############################################################################
##     MAIN 
###############################################################################

main()
```

Comment: In the future, please format your question as per [How to Ask](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), in particular "**Titling your question**".

Answer (score 1):

DRTW: don't reinvent the wheel. Python provides extensive libraries for:

- [logging](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/logging.html)
- [parsing command-line arguments](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/argparse.html)

If you take advantage of these built-in modules you can minimize the amount of code required. You can probably divide the code base by two without any loss of functionality.

I repeat myself from other topics, but here is how you could do your logging:

```
import logging
import sys

log_file = '/home/anonymous/test.log'

# logging - source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733552/logger-configuration-to-log-to-file-and-print-to-stdout
# Change root logger level from WARNING (default) to NOTSET in order for all messages to be delegated.
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.NOTSET)

# Add stdout handler, with level INFO
console = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
console.setLevel(logging.INFO)
formater = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
console.setFormatter(formater)
logging.getLogger().addHandler(console)

# Add file handler, with level DEBUG
handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file)
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formater = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s\t%(filename)s\t%(lineno)s\t%(name)s\t%(funcName)s\t%(levelname)s\t%(message)s', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
handler.setFormatter(formater)
logging.getLogger().addHandler(handler)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# this line will appear on console and in the log file
logger.info(f"Application started")

# this line will only appear in the log file because level = debug
logger.debug(f"Log some gory details here")
```

In this example I am logging to the console and to a log file at the same time so you can track progress and keep a permanent record of activity. But the log file contains more details, like procedure name, line number, etc. The console will not print messages that have a debug level (= fewer details).

In your case you may want to add more **destinations**. If you want to have multiple log files no problem.

And if the built-in logging module is not sufficient for your needs you can still derive your own class from it to add necessary enhancements.

---

To parse and validate **command-line arguments** at the same time:

```
import argparse

# check command line options
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
# Number of days to keep: short form = -dk
parser.add_argument('--synchdd_days_keep', '-dk', dest="days_to_keep", 
type=int, choices=range(10), required=True, help="Number of days to keep: a value between 0 and 9")

args = parser.parse_args()

# show the values
print(f"Number of days to keep: {args.days_to_keep}")
```

This code expects an integer value for the argument `--synchdd_days_keep` but for demonstration purposes will also accept an alternative, short form: `-dk`. The integer must also be in the range 0->9.

Usage:
Run with option `-h` to display the built-in help.
will work: `-dk 1`
will not work: `-dk 10`

That's it. Parsing and validating parameters with a minimum of code. Let Python do the job for you. The functionality is already available. I think this code can still be improved/prettified a bit. It's up to you to decide which arguments should be mandatory and which ones are optional.

My advice would to get a manual or tutorial about Python, and have a quick look at the standard features. Had you been aware, you would not have coded all those functions. There are better alternatives.

---

One more tip: using F-strings to avoid string concatenations.
Instead of:

```
log(0,"main: Available space: " + str(availableSpace) + " Necessary space: " + str(necessarySpace), file)
```

Use:

```
print(f"Available space: {availableSpace} - Necessary space: {necessarySpace}")
```

With logger:

```
logger.info(f"Available space: {availableSpace} - Necessary space: {necessarySpace}")
```